# Need help to prove this Logarithm below is correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that:    $$\log_{b^n}a^m=\frac{m}{n} \cdot \log_{b}a$$

Answer (score 1):

We can prove it using the power rule and the change of base rule:
$$
\log_{b^n}(a^m) = \frac{\log(a^m)}{\log(b^n)} = \frac{m \log a}{n\log b} = \frac{m}{n} \log_b(a)
$$